# Practice Problem Books

Tags: reference-request, big-list, book-recommendation

The Analysis I/II/III (Differentiation and Continuity/Sequence and Series/Integration) published by AMS. [The first one is this](http://books.google.de/books?id=HrO6QzUHU-gC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Analysis+I&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GF3oUZjdG4PsswaSh4DgDA&redir_esc=y). It's a problem-solution book. I found it excellent because of the quality of questions there.

I am looking for similar book (complete problem (only) book with complete solution) in linear algebra. However, let's include following subjects too:

1. Linear Algebra
2. Abstract Algebra
3. Complex Analysis
4. Topology

Please suggest if only it is like the book i suggested in the beginning. I do not want books like exceptions in analysis/mathematics which also have significant problems which are interesting. I also do not want books that are completely aimed for competitions like putnam and are too tough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analysis

**A problem Book in real analysis**, Asuman G. Askoy

**Problems and Solutions for Undergraduate Analysis**, Rami Shakirachi based
on Lang's Analysis book

**Problems and Theorems in Analysis** I, II and III, Polya, Szego(I think this was what you were referring)

Linear Algebra

**Linear Algebra**, Jim Hefferon, http://joshua.smcvt.edu/linearalgebra/ has the text book which has all problems and solutions.

Complex Analysis

**Problems and Solutions for Complex Analysis**, Rami Shakirachi based on Lang's complex analysis book.

Abstract Algebra

**Abstract Algebra, John Beachy** http://www.math.niu.edu/~beachy/abstract_algebra/study_guide/contents.html is an online text with problems and solutions.

**Solution Manual for A first course in Abstract Algebra**, Fraleigh . The solution manual has solutions to almost all problems if I recall and can find it online.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here are the few ones I know of:

- Linear Algebra:
  Challenging problems in linear algebra- an undergrad level problem book, whole solutions are not given but there are hints to the problems at the back.
  linear algebra by Friedberg,Insel- mainly a textbook, and problems are not too hard either, but I'm listing it here because it has complete solutions to every problem online in a pdf.
- Berkely problems in Mathematics- contains a lot of interesting problems on each topic like real analysis, linear algebra, complex analysis etc,etc..
  Solutions are also given.